# User generated lobbies or rooms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a sort of gameroom or lobby, that one user can create, and then let it be visible for others, so that they can join too.

But I am not sure on how to implement this. I'm thinking something along the lines of creating a new Room model and giving it attributes such as title, max number of players etc.. but I don't know how to store the users who are currently in the room. Could I store them as an array in the database or is there perhaps a better way?

Comment: please put whatever you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

You'll find this post very useful I think.  Persisting connections/users and the like CAN be done in a standard SQL persisted database, but consider the time it would take to write and read all of that data.  Instead you'll probably want to do a little research on common approaches.  Here is a newer approach that people are using with rails.  I think this blog post is a great place to start http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html.